# Time not updating in label after selection in TimePicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, timepicker

I am new to IOS i need to display time picker with current time in label and changed in time picker that  value also updated in same label. After that i want to close that time Picker also after selection.

Coding for time picker:

```
- (IBAction)pickuptime1:(id)sender {

    self.datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    self.datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 250,325,300); // set frame as your need
    self.datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
    [self.view addSubview: self.datePicker];
    //UILabel  * label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 70, 300, 50)];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
    NSString *currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date];
    label2.text = currentTime;
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [self.view addSubview:datePicker];
    [self.view addSubview:label2];

   }
```

Method coding:

```
- (void)dateChanged:(id)sender
{

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
    NSString *currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date];
    NSLog(@"%@", currentTime);


}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "close the time picker" ?

Comment: After selected in time picker i want to close that view or picker @marosoaie

Comment: you just need to hide the view,there is no close option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

accepted
Implement the delegate method, pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:. This is called by the picker view when you select an item. Get the value from your array based on the row and component, and populate your label.

```
 - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
     self.label.text = _myArray[row];
 }
```

Or check this one also

- You can't change the appearance of UIDatePicker.
- You can store it in a property and when you need to remove it from
  superview call [datePicker removeFromSuperview];
- You need a date formatter to get a string value from date. Some like
  this:

  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
   [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
- And for setting the label with date:

  self.dateLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];

Comment: can u explain this code" [datePicker removeFromSuperview];" @Vijay Kachhadiya

Comment: yes, If you don't want date picker more after selection than you can remove it. If tou need picker that skip this code

Comment: k fine but Superview means... i used only date picker in button  @Vijay Kachhadiya

Comment: Superview means parent view which contain your date picker

Comment: k fine but where i call"  [datePicker removeFromSuperview]; "@vijay Kachhaiya

Comment: Do you want delete it? If yes than set this code where you want to delete it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111910/discussion-between-a-sonu-and-vijay-kachhadiya).

Comment: but if i put in "- (void)dateChanged:(id)sender " in this method means its when first click itself dataPicker disappear @vijay Kachhadiya

Answer (score 0):

its quite simple you just need to implement a single method enables to update date & time implicitly have a look below code ..

```
-(IBAction)done_action:(id)sender{
    self.viewDatePicker.hidden=YES;
    [self.datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
    [self.datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(onDatePickerValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    _yourCustomLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date];
}

// method invokes while scrolling on date picker
-(IBAction)onDatePickerValueChanged:(UIDatePicker *)datePicker{
    // yourLabel to show current time while scroll on datePicker
    self.yourLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
}
```

place your datePicker inside a view which is initially hide or customize accordingly ..

Comment: please explain this line "self.viewDatePicker.hidden=YES;" @vaibhav

Comment: @A.sonu sure ..initially we have a uiview named _viewDatePicker_ which contains **uibuttons** (cancel and done), **datepicker** and a **uilabel**  _(shows current time and date while scrolling on datePicker)_ once you select date finally and press done this hides _viewDatePicker_ executes bunch of code ..

Comment: k fine but i didn't put any done or cancel button in my date picker@vaibhav